# Can carry SVN actions remotely, but failing at localhost (Linux)

Tags: linux, svn

I've been successfully using my SVN server from multiple remote clients. Ie, executing

```
svn list svn+ssh://my.ip.add.ress/path
```

Gives the list of repositories as expected.

However, today I've found that if I execute exactly the same command on the machine where the the SVN server is installed, I get error:

```
svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://my.ip.add.ress/path'
```

Changing my.ip.add.ress to localhost or 127.0.0.1 doesn't help.

What's going on and how to fix it? I desperately need to establish a working copy of one project on the same PC where the SVN server is, and this unexpected issue got in my way.

Comment: Why not just do `svn list file:///path`?

Comment: Oh, that raises some messy issues. The permissions to access repo path is only to user svn. If I'd do checkout as user svn then the created files are owned by user svn. But I want to be logged on as myself and carry out the svn actions as myself.

Comment: Does either `svn list svn://my.ip.add.ress/path` or `svn list svn://localhost/path`

Answer (score 0):

Damn, the problem turned out to be the permissions related. The user I was logged on did not have rights to access the SVN server. I had to write

```
svn list svn+ssh://goodUser@my.ip.add.ress/path
```

To get access, and it works like charm.

Had I got "access denied" error, I could have found this out earlier. The "no repository found" message was very misleading.